# Request.Form threw an exception of type 'System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException'

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I've read a few articles on the error:

```
Request.Form = 'Request.Form' threw an exception of type 'System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException'
```

But I don't know if I'm missing a point or just don't understand it well or even if they don't apply to this problem.

I have a response coming into a webpage to take relevant actions, i.e. write values to a database etc. So the response arrives at page load, I debug `Request.Form.ToString()` and I immediately see the above error message. I give it around 2 seconds and `Request.Form.ToString()` now has the response I want to action.

If I do this in real time then I get the above error, but in debug mode I wait around 2 seconds then it proceeds to the next step. Am I missing something here or have I done this incorrectly?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you trying to `.ToString` the `Request.Form` collection?

Comment: What im doing is passing the form to another procedure to split the response into properties etc - I could try and change the parameter to accept a form if you feel that could be a cause?

Comment: I'm not sure if it would be the cause (as every .Net class should support a .ToString method c.f. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspx) but it seems unnecessary.  I'd pass the Form collection directly and see if the behavior changes at all.  Just to confirm: you're experiencing this in your Page_Load event handler (and not in Page_Init or somewhere else), correct?

Comment: A debugging idea: have you tried adding <%@ Page validateRequest="false" %> to your page to see if the error goes away?  It should - but if not, it would lead me to think something deeper is amiss.  Also, have you tried isolating what part of your form is causing the exception by removing all of the fields and then adding them back one at a time until you get the exception?

Comment: Also, you aren't trying to have the user input HTML into a field, are you?

Comment: Page_Load only (not page_init). Passing Request.Form to my function had the same issue. page validation request is already in the config file. When i looked into the error message there is one field that its complaining about ""A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (Amount=\"&#163;5.00\"" but im not sure how to tackle this one as its in the Request.Form collection? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Did you say that you've turned OFF page validation via <%@ Page validateRequest="false" %>?  If so, this error should not occur.

Comment: What are you entering into this field from the browser?

Comment: I double checked the config file and i have <pages enableEventValidation="false"/> under system.web. The reason why i have this in the config file is because this is a user control. Nothing is entered, it is a response coming from a third party system to a URL at my end.

Comment: Ah - is the 3rd party using an HTTP GET or an HTTP POST to invoke your code?

Comment: Its HTTP POST and yes 3rd party

Comment: Your user control must be instantiated within another web form (.aspx file) - can you post that?  Also, try adding the <%@ Page validateRequest="false" %> to your .aspx file - if the setting in web.config was working correctly, there shouldn't be any reason you are still getting this exception (although that doesn't fix the original problem). Something weird is going on here - finding a way to silence the exception temporarily is perhaps the first step in finding out what it is.

Comment: Thanks JimMSDN - after carefully checking and going through it with a clear head i managed to fix it. It was a combination of adding to the page and config that did the trick - thanks again. I would have marked your last reply as an answer as that was the closest to getting it correct :)

Comment: Hehe...although I'll take the credit, I don't think the root issue has been solved as you're only suppressing the error. You shouldn't have to turn off request validation.  If you trust the 3rd party, though, perhaps this is good enough - but remember, if someone else discovers your URL they could now inject maliciousness into your program which, if not equipped to handle it correctly, could lead to security issues.